# Run docker Kaggle/python on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python, docker

I'm having a warnings running docker Kaggle/python on Ubuntu:

1. Docker version 20.10.1 (build 831ebea) installed on Ubuntu 20.04.
2. kaggle/python (993897c5431c) pulled docker pull kaggle/python
3. Different running options:

   ```
   docker run -v ${PWD}:/tmp/working -w=/tmp/working -p 8888:8888 --rm -it kaggle/python bash -c "jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tmp/working --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
   ```
4. are giving me the same warning:

   ```
   **[W 12:40:11.750 NotebookApp] Config option `allow_remote_access` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.  Did you mean one of: `allow_credentials, allow_root`?**

   [I 12:40:11.764 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret

   **[W 12:40:12.016 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.**

   **[W 12:40:12.016 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.**

   jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket

   [I 12:40:12.969 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
   ```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/kaggle/python says the images on docker hub are stale and you should get them from google repos : quote "Our Python Docker images are now stored on Google Container Registry at:

    CPU-only: gcr.io/kaggle-images/python
    GPU: gcr.io/kaggle-gpu-images/python
"

Comment: it seems the latest image on docker hub still corresponds with the latest image on gcr.io's hub -> no issue yet

Comment: if you launch docker run -v $PWD:/tmp/working -w=/tmp/working -p 8080:8080 --rm -it gcr.io/kaggle-images/python     -- you can then visit http://127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 0):

if you launch

`docker run -v $PWD:/tmp/working -w=/tmp/working -p 8080:8080 --rm -it gcr.io/kaggle-images/python`

you can then visit http://127.0.0.1:8080

you could also run

`docker run -v $PWD:/tmp/working -w=/tmp/working -p 8080:8080 --rm -it gcr.io/kaggle-images/python jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip="*" --notebook-dir=/tmp/working --allow-root`

Comment: Hi Koen, thanks for the answer. however the same warnings appear for option both options